# Packets Are Stacked When Sent at Regular Intervals

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, bsd

I am trying to send a message over a TCP socket at a regular interval (every second). Sometimes the full message will not be sent or two-four messages will be stacked and sent at once. I have if statements for if the return value is 0 or < 0, but those are never true. I tried the obvious approach of checking the exact return value of send() to see if less or more bytes were sent. It just returns the number that I specify in the parameter to send (which makes sense if send blocks until it sends that much), even if less bytes are sent. So is there an accurate way to say "was the right size packet sent? no? - do something"?

Comment: How do you know the problem is on the send side and not on the receive side?  If you want a real answer, you will probably need to include both send and receive example code.

Comment: @antlersoft: Code isn't really important here... it's the concept that it important.

Comment: Yeah now that I think about it, it would make more sense to check the accurateness of the bytes on the receiving side. But I'm assuming the same procedure can be used on the read side.

Comment: You should have some indicator in your messages so you know how to split your message such as a message ID and size plus checksum.

Comment: The bottom line is that TCP is almost certainly the wrong thing to use for this problem. Under the circumstances, UDP probably makes more sense. Depending on the situation, you may need to build more on top of UDP (that's pretty common), but it's more suitable as a base for what you're doing (i.e., it may not do everything you want, but at least it doesn't do a lot you really don't want).

Comment: 0A0D, thank you. I would have accepted yours if it was an actual answer. I just made the messages-to-be-sent have a header, followed by length, followed by the message and only send the message if it contains exactly one header (the length comes into play when I interpret it). Didn't implement a checksum though.

Comment: Well, I check it before and I send and then again when it gets to the other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP provides a reliable *stream* of bytes, there's no message boundary. If you need to know the length of the message you have to build this into the protocol, eg: send every message with a 2 byte header which specifies the message length.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such facility with TCP. It's up to the in-kernel network stack how to slice TCP *stream* into packets. Having said that you can set [**`TCP_NODELAY`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html) option on your socket to disable [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't really do anything. Thank you for the knowledge for future reference though.

Comment: TCP_NODELAY helps latency with small application writes (telnet, rsh, ssh do character at a time) but does not guarantee any particular packetization.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you right, sometimes you send two or more packets and they are received as one on the distant end.

This is the nature of TCP/IP. You cannot guarantee the packets will arrive as distinct, just that they will arrive in order and reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what platform you are using or what syntax you are using (streams, `FILE` objects or file descriptors; some code would clarify this) but you may need to do an explicit `flush` operation after you write each *message* to force the kernel. I generally use C-style file descriptors and it is usually sufficient to call `fflush` on the descriptors to make whatever I've queued up go out immediately.